# Use `less` to view BIG (multi-gigabyte) CSV files

Tags: command-line

I have a *big* (multi-gigabyte) CSV file, which I am viewing with a puny computer.

I would like to view my file using `less` or some command like it which doesn't have to read the whole file at once to show me part of it.

Is there a command out there which can show me my file in comma-aligned columns?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a csv column formatting question on another [StackOverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875305/command-line-csv-viewer) - does this work for your very-large file?

```
cat somefile.csv | column -s, -t | less -#2 -N -S
```

Comment: This will not work. Because cat will try to print the entire file, which may be gigabytes worth of data. It may be that there's a buffer somewhere in the pipes which prevents this situation, but I'm not sure and a complete answer using `cat` would have to address this. If there were such a buffer, I'd begin to wonder if the data was then being cached by `less`.

Comment: ok - please add this comment to your question - it will give a better understanding that you are manipulating big=multi gigabytes!!

Comment: I'd assumed that _big_ was a sufficient descriptor! I'll make a note of that, thanks.

Comment: Can you use `tail` or `head` instead of `cat` to get the last 10 or first 10 records, then pipe that into `column`? `head file.csv | column <options> | less <options>`. I am not sure if `head` or `tail` will read the entire file _THEN_ output the desired rows...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried vim with a 514M text file. It has 8032416 lines and after it loaded for around 30 seconds, I could run around the file very smoothly.

It took 30% of my 2GB RAM, and vim created a 2.2M swap file. Sounds reasonable.

`tail` gave me instant results on that file, it probably seeks to the bottom and then goes up until it reaches 10 lines and then prints them.